# Facebook integration for app in android

Tags: android, facebook

I have included Facebook feature in my app. I have couple of problems here:

I have login and log out feature in my app but then If I logout from my facebook app. My app's facebook is also getting logged out. I am not sure why this is happening?

Using the help of: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-facebook-connect-tutorial/

For that I have two questions:

1. Can I have independent Facebook integration like Facebook app installed or not or Facebook app installed logged in or not? I should be able to login or log out in my app. is this possible?
2. If it is not possible can I know if Facebook app is logged in or not on a phone?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The example you provided uses old SDK. I'm using SDK3.0 and your app won't log out if you log out from facebook app. You can follow https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/ from Facebook instead. There are couple of examples in SDK you could follow to grasp the idea. Hope that helps.